Google Sheets: Repeat "Product SKUs" for 5 rows per SKU in another Sheet
Basically I need to get SKUs in one sheet formatted like this:



Column A




SKU 1


SKU 2


SKU 3



To become formatted like this in another sheet:



Column A




SKU 1


SKU 1


SKU 1


SKU 1


SKU 1


SKU 2


SKU 2


SKU 2


SKU 2


SKU 2


SKU 3


SKU 3


SKU 3


SKU 3


SKU 3



Ad nauseum so that it will pick up all new SKUS to do the same
I've only gotten so far as to do this:
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE('US Price List'!$B5&"~"),5),"~")))
But when I try this:
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE('US Price List'!$B$5:B&"~"),5),"~")))
I only get a repeat of the full list 5 times instead of the result I want wherein the repeated SKUs stay together.
I've also looked into FLATTEN and I can't figure out how to get this to continue down the sheet cleanly. Not sure how I can do this with LAMBDA either.


You may try:
=tocol(map(tocol('US Price List'!B5:B,1),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,5,Σ))))


Amazing, now I need to learn what it all means!

Alternative answer found by a friend using AI:

=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT('Pricing Worksheet'!$A$2:$A&"|", 5), "|")))

